# How to add vmware tag to a virtual machine if it has spaces in the tag name

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am trying to create a script that adds "Tags" to my virtual machine.  I am using Powershell/PowerCLI to do this.  I am able to add the names if there are no spaces in the tag name. For example, Application tag is name "Test" and it adds it to the server fine.  But if the owner name is "John Doe" it will not take because of the space.  Here is myscript thus far:

```
$vCenter = "test.com"
$ServerName = "test1"

Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Connect-ViServer -server $vCenter -ErrorAction Stop 

$AppTag = Read-Host "What is the Application tag name for $ServerName"
$myTag1 = Get-Tag $AppTag
$myVM = Get-VM "$ServerName"
New-TagAssignment -Tag $myTag1 -Entity $myVM

$AppOwnerTag = Read-Host "What is the Application Owner tag name for $ServerName"
$myTag2 = Get-Tag $AppOwnerTag
$myVM = Get-VM $ServerName
New-TagAssignment -Tag $myTag2 -Entity $myVM

$CreatedByTag = Read-Host "What is the Created By tag name for $ServerName"
$myTag3 = Get-Tag $CreatedByTag
$myVM = Get-VM $ServerName
New-TagAssignment -Tag $myTag3 -Entity $myVM
```

Comment: Excuse my lack of vmware-experience, but is spaces allowed in tag names at all? Whitespace and special characters are usually not recommended. I would suggest replacing space with `_` as a workaround. Ex. `$AppOwnerTag = (Read-Host "What is the Application Owner tag name for $ServerName") -replace ' ', '_'`

Comment: If you get an error message, please update the question to include that. Spaces in tag names don't give me any trouble with New-TagAssignment in v5.8R1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use spaces in your tag names.  The problem you are running into may be due to the version of PowerShell, or an issue if you have multiple tags with the same name or the same tag across vCenters:

- First confirm your PowerShell VMware PowerCLI version is at least 6.5.3 with the command `Get-PowerCLIVersion`, or if you like to be fancy `Get-Module -Name VMware.* | Select Name,Version`.  According to [VMware PowerCLI Blog for version 6.5.3](https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2017/10/new-release-powercli-6-5-3.html), New-TagAssignment has a related issue and has been fixed.  If you are unsure how to upgrade or install VMware PowerCLI, you can `Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI` as Administrator as described in this other [VMware PowerCLI Installation Blog](https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2017/04/powercli-install-process-powershell-gallery.html) if you have the PackageManager installed as described in this [4sysops](https://4sysops.com/archives/installing-and-removing-programs-with-the-powershell-package-manager/) article.
- Another thing is to confirm that the correct and only one vCenter is active if your query.  For example, you may need to modify your command to `New-TagAssignment -Tag $myTag3 -Entity $myVM  -Server $vCenter`.  The $vCenter is the same name you use when you `Connect-VIServer $vCenter`, which in your case I assume is "test.com".  If you logged into, and not out of, other vCenters before performing this query, this may be your fix. For example, I do not see `Disconnect-VIServer $vCenter` at the bottom of your script which is why I suggest this.
- The last thing to try is you may have the same tag name in multiple tag categories.  The recommendation in [VMware Communities](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/572551) is to get the tag explicitly by specifying the category in the command, such as `$myTag1 = Get-Tag $AppTag -Category $myCategory`.  Another less desirable option may be to rename your tags in those categories so they do not overlap.